# CSS: How can I position an element relative to an image with background-size: cover?

Tags: css

I'm making a game and have a series of "room" images which scale (and are cropped if necessary) to fit the browser window using `background-size: cover`.

I want to position some in-game elements on top of key locations on these images, but this is proving tricky as the room images change position/scale as the browser size changes.

I have a simple demo here: https://jsfiddle.net/p4p699cn/3/embedded/result/ – ideally, I'd be able to position the red 'X' on top of the tree, so that when the browser (or in this case, containing `<div>` element) is resized, the inner 'X' maintains its position relative to the original image's proportions rather than the browser window.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how this could be accomplished?

Comment: You need to keep track of the ratio between the actual width of image and the cropped one. For finding the actual image size you could use a virtual img element, set its src same as the bg img url and get the size of the image. Now find the size of the element that holds the bg image. Depending on the width/height ratio between actual img size and the element you can determine whether width or height will be cropped. You can use this info to find the relative position. Hope this might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to achieve almost what is needed through the usage of a simple `<img/>` tag instead of a CSS `background`. However, it is not identical to `background-size: cover` and would require to make some assumptions on the min/max size of the image. The following is your code, slightly modified. Notice also `display: inline-block` on the `inner` box, it is important.

```css
body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 3px solid #cccccc;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

.marker {
  font-size: 48px;
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 63%;
  left: 7%;
  padding-left: 20%;
  transform: translate(0, -100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="marker">X</div>
    <img src="http://feelgrafix.com/data/landscape/landscape-3.jpg" height="2848" width="4288" class="img" />
  </div>
</div>

drag this box to resize it
```